# How to control access to EC2 and RDS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-cognito

I have an Android app in which I've implemented AWS Cognito.  I'm hoping to use this as a means for controlling access to PHP scripts on my web root which connect to an RDS instance with a MySQL db.  So far, I've set the registration process in my app to use a developer authenticated id to register the user in a cognito identity pool.  Now, what I would like to do is have a method for checking whether the user trying to access the various scripts I've exposed in my web root is indeed a verified user.  What I was thinking of doing is implementing a script like this:

```
use Aws\CognitoIdentity\CognitoIdentityClient;

$identityId = $_POST['identityId'];//sending cached identity id from client

$client = CognitoIdentityClient::factory ( array (
        'profile' => 'profile',
        'region' => 'region' 
) );
$result = $client->lookupDeveloperIdentity(array(
    'IdentityPoolId' => 'IdentityPoolId',
    'IdentityId' => $identityId,
    'MaxResults' => 1,
));

if ($result != null) {
    //connect to db and do whatever operation/query needs to be done
}
```

However, checking this every time I need to make some kind of transaction on my db seems to be pretty inefficient and slow. 
a) Am I using Cognito in the intended fashion?
b) If not, what is a better way of going about this?

Please let me know if I'm way off base here.  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it would be a better idea to use standard sessions once you have established the identity?

Comment: Again, maybe I'm way off here, but my goal is to verify that whoever is accessing my resources is a verified user.  I thought that's what Cognito was meant for and I'm trying to leverage that to handle access to my database. For other AWS resources, such as S3, the Android SDK handles this access management for us by requiring us to pass it a valid Cognito ID, with required permissions in order to upload/download. I;m looking for something similar here. If you have some kind of example that you think would be relevant, considering that I'm developing an Android app, that'd be helpful.  Thanks